# UI Router 1.0 state change events not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I'm migrating my Angular 1.5 application to Angular UI Router 1.0-beta3 to use the component router. I'm listening for state change events on $rootScope but none of the events are fired.

Example:

```
angular
    .module('app', [ 'ui.router' ])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state(
            'dashboard',
            {
                url: '/dashboard',
                component: 'dashboardComponent',
                resolve: {
                    enabled: function() { throw new Error('NOT ENABLED'); }
                }
            });
    })
    .run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function() {
            // Never called
        });
    });
```

Are state change events supported in component routing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

State change events are supported in component routing, but UI Router handles events differently in v1.0.

Try this:

```
...

.run(function($transitions) {
    $transitions.onError({}, function() {
        // Works like a charm
    });
});
```

See the [docs](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/1.0.0-beta.3/classes/transition.transitionservice.html#onerror) for more info

Comment: If you still want to use rootScope events then you need to include stateEvents.js and add it as a dependancy ui.router.state.events

Comment: @fernando Good point. However, state events are deprecated in ui-router v. 1.0. [The docs](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/1.0.0-beta.3/modules/ng1_state_events.html) recommend moving to transition hooks instead.

Comment: Yup and it's very powerful as well. We are heavily using state events in current project